# Django inheritance: I'm trying to add a new child but instead modifies the existing one

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have 3 models that inherit from an abstract model:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    field_pk = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', default=0)
    fieldone = CharField()
    fieldtwo = CharField()

    class Meta:
         abstract = True
...

class Child1(ParentModel):
      MyField1 = CharField()
...

class Child2(ParentModel):
      MyField2 = CharField()
...

class Child3(ParentModel):
      MyField3 = CharField()
...
```

In django admin, when I try to add an instance of one of the three children, it modifies the existing one.
 Someone here can explain to me why this happening and how to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "modifies the existing one"? Please give an example!

Comment: I have only one object in my database, when i try to add another object, it modifies the only existing in db.

Comment: Django ORM will save an existing record if the primary key field is filled in (and exists). What field are you using for primary key? And are you sure it is not filled in?

Comment: I defined a AutoField as primary key only in the parent class, like this:
`field_pk = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', default=0)`

Comment: Can you please post the code where you save objects to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that: as you defined a primary key with default '0', this value is picked when you edit your models in the admin page. The same primary key will save to the same entry. You should probably leave the `default` option out, and leave django/ your database to generate an id

Comment: Thanks, that's work well, but I do not understand why sometimes django imposes to give a default value to primary key field!!

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense, does it? A primary key is supposed to be unique. What do you want to achive with the default value? I believe there will be a better way :)

Comment: I was not trying to give a default value but when applying migrations it requires a default value!